# Journal themes for regression table using gtsummary package throws an error in the table

Tags: r, regression, gtsummary

Using gtsummary package, when I try to style my regression table to a journal format (Lancet in this case), I get the following error in my table:

`exp(Beta)=0Â·24  95% CI= 0Â·03 to 2Â·11    p-value= <0Â·001`

I dont know what this Â mean.

I expect my table be like:
`exp(Beta)=0.24  95% CI= 0.03, 2.11     p-value= <0.001`

I trying the code:
`theme_gtsummary_journal(journal = "lancet") lancet_theme <- tbl_regression(model1, exponentiate = TRUE) %>% modify_caption("Lancet Theme") print(lancet_theme)`

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: The midpoint is a non-ascii character and it looks like you have a local encoding issue. If you'd like anyone else to check in their machines, you'll need to update your post with a minimal reproducible example.